# iPhone photos widget is grey

Tags: iphone, photos, widgets

That's pretty much it: my photos widget is just a grey tile, no matter which size I get. I've already rebooted the device and it still doesn't work. How to fix this?

It's an iPhone 12 device with iOS 16.1.1 on it.

Comment: Have you tried removing the app, rebooting and re-downloading it?

Comment: @SteveChambers one can't remove the Photos app.

Comment: Odd, Photos.app on my iPhone 14 with iOS 16.2 gives the option to delete that very app. I have not then deleted it but assume a deletion would not be made available if the menu didn't work.

Comment: @SteveChambers weirdly enough, I can only remove it from the home screen. 

Comment: What have you got in the For You tab in Photos?

Comment: @Thinkr I got the usual favorited pictures plus some memories created by the phone itself, as usual. But it's a bit embarrassing the problem just went away on its own after a week of two. Seemingly app update related.

Comment: @FernandoD'Andrea Your iPhone has been syncing photos, to go through all of your photos, it'll take a long time of course. It needs to analyse the photos for people, places and others features in order to provide a varied and user-appreciated widget.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience some of the widgets incluging Photos the iPhone needs to be connected to the internet for a while. This seems to be because the phone needs to calculate which photos to show you.